# Rails and ActiveJobs - can I 'join' them like threads?

Tags: sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm looking for a design pattern that will let me 'join' several ActiveJobs so that when they're all finished, I can continue with another task.

Say I have jobs A, B and C which take various amounts of time to complete. When they're ALL complete I want to initiate job D.

Is this a common design pattern? What can I use to achieve this? I thought of a table in the database which just keeps count of the total number of jobs left to complete, then as each complete it decrements the counter and when it's at zero, task D is queued. But I think there might be issues with the counter - I'd need to lock the table between read and write?

(This is Rails 6 and Sidekiq 6)

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Sidekiq, this is known as a Batch. It's a commercial feature in Sidekiq Pro.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Batches

Comment: Thank you, I see there is also a third-party gem called sidekiq-batch as well, which does a similar job.

Comment: That gem has numerous bugs and provides no support to its users. My Batch hasn't had a bug found in over a year and I'm here supporting you. You get what you pay for.